# <input></input> in innerHTML not working

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu

I created a dropdown list with javascript and I populate it getting data from a MySQL database.

The problem that I have is that I can't place the dropdown list in the innerHTML code.

This is what I wrote to create the dropdown list with JS:

```
var mySpan = document.getElementById('myDiv');

var myLine = document.getElementById('testcat');
myLine.value++;

// Create select
var selection = document.createElement('select');
selection.setAttribute('name',"category[]");
mySpan.appendChild(selection); 

// Create Option
createSelectOption(selection);

// Create the container
var ni = document.getElementById('myDiv');
ni.setAttribute('style', 'width:790px;');
...........
...........
```

Then I create other things and to create the HTML code, I use:

```
newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="table">.........</div>';
ni.appendChild(newdiv);
```

This is the part of HTML:

```
// test dropdown list
<input name="testcat" id="testcat" type="hidden" value="0" />   
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

I tested my dropdown list as you can see in the code above, and it works if I declare `<input name="testcat" id="testcat" type="hidden" value="0" />` in the HTML (I mean in the `<body></body>`), but if I use the same code in the innerHTML, FireBug tells me: "myLine is null; myLine.value++;".

Any help?

Comment: Do you have any break lines in your HTML? Also this is very BAD idea to insert HTML using `innerHTML` use `document.createElement` and `appendChild` methods instead.

Comment: are you doing them **after** the page has completed loading? If not it will fail

Comment: Have you tried it as a self-closing tag `<input name="testcat" id="testcat" type="hidden" value="0"/>` (note slash before closing angle bracket)?

Comment: @antyrat: in the HTML yes, but you mean in the innerHTML? Nope. Why?

Comment: @NejiHyuga: what do you mean?

Comment: @EdDaniel: yes sorry, I tried that and not what I wrote (edited now).

Comment: To be more clear, I did this:
`newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="table"><ul><li><input name="testcat" id="testcat" type="hidden" value="0" /></li></ul></div>'`;

Comment: accept answers to your previous questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't assign an element with an ID using innerHTML as text - the ID won't register on the DOM. You need to first create the element, assign it the ID and then put that element in the DOM.

You might find this easier using jQuery:

```
var input = document.createElement("input"); 
input.id="testcat"; 
input.innerHTML = "testcat" ;
$('somediv').appendChild(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did in my old code:

```
var selectcat = document.createElement("select");
selectcat.name = "category[]";
selectcat.options[0] = new Option("","");
selectcat.options[1] = new Option("cat1","cat1");
selectcat.options[2] = new Option("cat2","cat2");
..........
..........
selectcat.options[12] = new Option("cat1","cat12");
```

And the used:

```
newdiv.innerHTML = '<div class="table"><ul><li><select name="category[]"><option value=""></option><option value="cat1">cat1</option><option value="cat2">cat2</option></select></li></ul></div>';
```

But now I have to get the values from a MySQL database.

So I created this function:

```
function createSelectOption(element)
    {
        var objSelect = ele;
        var Item = new Option("", "");
        objSelect.options[objSelect.length] = Item;
        <?
        while($categ = mysql_fetch_array($resultf_categ))
        {
        ?>
            var Item = new Option("<?=$categ["cat_name"];?>", "<?=$categ["cat_name"];?>");
            objSelect.options[objSelect.length] = Item;
        <?
        }
        ?>
    }
```

But still don't understand how can I use directly in my innerHTML.
Sorry for the stupid questions, but I am really stucked here.

Comment: ok, I rewrote the entire code, removed innerHTML and now I sorted.
Give me some time to clean the code and I will post my solution.

Thank you everyone for the hints, expecially antyrat and Robbie, thank you.

Comment: Following the hints, I rewrote the function, removed the innerHTML and created all the input fields and dropdown list, like this:
`// Create input text (Name of the Image)
var namePic = document.createElement('input');
namePic.setAttribute('type',"text");
namePic.setAttribute('name',"name[]");
namePic.setAttribute('id',"img_name"+myLine.value);
mySpan.appendChild(namePic); 

// Create select (DropDown List - Category)
var cat = document.createElement('select');
cat.setAttribute('name',"category[]");
cat.setAttribute('id',"category"+myLine.value);
mySpan.appendChild(cat);`